# ceph-rest-api on a test server

Tags: linux, rest, ceph

When trying to run ceph-rest-api on a general ceph cluster named "ceph" it works without issue from cli:

```
/bin/ceph-rest-api --cluster ceph --id admin
  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

But, when I try to run it on a test cluster named "test" it errors out:

```
/bin/ceph-rest-api --cluster test --id test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ceph-rest-api", line 59, in <module>
    rest,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_rest_api.py", line 495, in generate_app
    addr, port = api_setup(app, conf, cluster, clientname, clientid, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_rest_api.py", line 106, in api_setup
    app.ceph_cluster.connect()
  File "rados.pyx", line 785, in rados.Rados.connect (rados.c:8969)
rados.ObjectNotFound: error connecting to the cluster
```

I've also tried using a variation and got a different error:

```
/bin/ceph-rest-api --cluster test --name test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ceph-rest-api", line 59, in <module>
    rest,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_rest_api.py", line 495, in generate_app
    addr, port = api_setup(app, conf, cluster, clientname, clientid, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_rest_api.py", line 104, in api_setup
    app.ceph_cluster = rados.Rados(name=clientname, conffile=conf)
  File "rados.pyx", line 525, in rados.Rados.__init__ (rados.c:5719)
  File "rados.pyx", line 425, in rados.requires.wrapper.validate_func (rados.c:4106)
  File "rados.pyx", line 557, in rados.Rados.__setup (rados.c:6237)
rados.Error: rados_initialize failed with error code: -22
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`rados.ObjectNotFound: error connecting to the cluster` for `/bin/ceph-rest-api --cluster test --id test` means the test user does not exist. Besides, according to ceph-rest-api man page, --name begins with client and --id begins without client.
i.e: 
`ceph-rest-api --cluster test --name client.admin`
or
`ceph-rest-api --cluster test --id admin`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a keyring file on the machine where ceph-rest-api should be started.

1. create a restapi user:
   `ceph auth get-or-create client.rest-test mds 'allow' osd 'allow *' mon 'allow *`

   Output should look like this
   `[client.rest-test]
       key = AQDPVTFZsiZjIRAAtLXWWlr8Q8t1PjhFKnOCyw==`
2. Create rest user keyring file `/etc/ceph/ceph-client.<username>.keyring`
   and paste the output from `ceph auth get-or-create` in that file or redirect the output when execute the command.
   You can always repeat the command `ceph auth get-or-create`, when the user is already created, ceph auth will get the user key und name in the same manner
3. start ceph-rest-api with
   `ceph-rest-api --name client.rest-test`
   or
   `ceph-rest-api --id rest-test`

## Research

I did some tests with strace to figure out what files ceph-rest-api is opening and reading before starting.
    `strace -e open ceph-rest-api  -i rest-test 2>&1  | grep key`

```
...
open("/etc/ceph/ceph.client.rest-test.keyring", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ceph/keyring", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ceph/keyring.bin", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

as you can see, ceph-rest-api tries to open some different keyfiles, in this case no key file is present and starting ceph-rest-api fails.
If you place the correct keyfile representing your rest-user in /etc/ceph, the file will be read and the rest-api will start.

```
strace -e open,connect ceph-rest-api  -i rest-test 2>&1  | grep -i 'key\|running'
open("/etc/ceph/ceph.client.rest-test.keyring", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/ceph/ceph.client.rest-test.keyring", O_RDONLY) = 3
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```